# Python-Shmython - "Y" is it so hard?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have written a program to implement [shm-reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication).

The rules are basically that if a word starts with a consonant (or a group of consonants) then you strip that off and add "shm", but if it starts with a vowel then you just add "shm". You also put the whole thing onto the end of the existing word.

The problem is the letter Y, because sometimes it is a consonant and sometimes it is a vowel. I want `you` to become `you-shmou`, but I want `Python` to become `Python-Shmython`. How can I handle this?

Here is my code so far.

```
import re

def word_shmord(word):
    orig = word
    if word.isupper():
        prefix = "SHM"
    elif word.istitle():
        word = word.lower()
        prefix = "Shm"
    else:
        prefix = "shm"
    position = re.search("[aeiou]", word, re.IGNORECASE).start()
    new = prefix + word[position:]
    return "{}-{}".format(orig, new)


text = """
All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood.
"""
text_shmext = re.sub("\w+", lambda m:word_shmord(m.group(0)), text)
print(text_shmext)
```

Comment: Not really. I would want `Skye-Shmye`. Maybe consonant only at the start of the word would work.

Comment: But do we care about the status of y in backyard? It just goes to shmackyard,

Answer (score 1):

I found this question quite amusing, so I coded-in some linguistic rules for this problem (or shall I say *shmoblem*).

```
import re
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize.sonority_sequencing import SyllableTokenizer

stop = stopwords.words('english')
tk = SyllableTokenizer()


def word_shmord(word):
    if (len(word) < 4 and word.lower() in stop) or not word.isalnum() or word.lower().startswith('shm'):
        return word
    if 'y' in word:
        y = word.find('y')
        # Y is considered to be a vowel if The word has no other vowel
        if len(re.findall("[aeiou]", word, re.IGNORECASE)) == 0 and word.count('y') == 1:
            word = word[:y] + '#' + word[y + 1:]
        # or if the letter is at the end of a word
        if word[-1] == 'y':
            word = word[:-1]+ '#'
        # or middle/end of syllable
        if word.find('y') != -1:
            syll = tk.tokenize(word)
            for i, s in enumerate(syll):
                snew = s[:-1] + '#' if s[-1] == 'y' else s
                y = snew.find('y')
                if len(snew) // 2 == y:
                    snew = snew[:y] + '#' + snew[y + 1:]
                syll[i] = snew
            word = ''.join(syll)

    if word.isupper():
        prefix = "SHM"
    elif word.istitle():
        word = word.lower()
        prefix = "Shm"
    else:
        prefix = "shm"
    vowels = re.search("[aeiou#]", word, re.IGNORECASE)
    if not vowels:
        return word
    position = vowels.start()
    new = prefix + word[position:].replace('#', 'y')
    return new


text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
text_shmext = ([word_shmord(x) for x in word_tokenize(text)])
# join strings
text_shmext = "".join([" " + i if i not in string.punctuation else i for i in text_shmext]).strip()
print(text_shmext)
```

Input: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Output: *The shmuick shmown shmox shmumps shmover the shmazy shmog*